# Conditionally set the AND/OR operator in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a following select query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE condition1 AND condition2 AND condition3 AND/OR condition4
```

The `AND/OR` here I want to be set base on another variable, e.g. `DECLARE @Operator [nvarchar](max) = 'AND'`. If `@Operator` is "AND", the operator here will be `AND`, and be similar for "OR".

Is there a good way to do that?

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Not sure which RDBMS you are using but what about using a CASE...WHEN for this?

Comment: Added tag Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would either dynamically construct the SQL statement or use a statement like this:

```
DECLARE @AndOperator BIT = 0; --set to 1 to use AND instead of OR
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE
  ((@AndOperator = 0 AND (condition1 AND condition2 AND condition3 OR  condition4)) OR
   (@AndOperator = 1 AND (condition1 AND condition2 AND condition3 AND condition4)))
```

Depending on the logical structure, additional simplifications might be possible.

Using dynamic SQL would have my preference in this case, but the statement above could be used in stored procedures.

Comment: I think this is more readable than my solution, and if I want to modify to be like `AND/OR (condition4 AND condition 5...)`, it's easier to do that.

Comment: Actually your solution is not correct in case @AndOperator is 1, the condition4 always be checked in the first block. Just need to wrap in parentheses like this to make it works: `(@AndOperator = 0 AND (condition1 AND condition2 AND condition3 OR  condition4))`

Comment: @Messi You are right. I edited my answer and added (unnecessary) parentheses as well for `@AndOperator = 1` (for the sake of structural consistency).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE condition1 AND condition2 AND condition3 AND 
(@Operator = 'OR' OR condition4) OR (@Operator = 'OR' AND condition4)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just have a solution but it's quite hard to read:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE condition1 AND condition2 AND condition3
  AND (@Operator = 'AND' AND condition4 OR @Operator <> 'AND')
  OR (@Operator = 'OR' AND condition4)
```